# How to add classes to image fields set to Unlimited and a "rel" attribute to the <a> tag that wraps them

Tags: media

I have an image field set to Unlimited and I have some questions on how to display them:

1. How do I display only the first image while all the rest are hidden (has `class="hide"`)?
2. Add a `rel="something"` attribute to each `<a>` which wraps `<img>`

**Answer to #1 found!** After several tests, simply capture the field by adding this to your `field.tpl.php` file. This will insert the `hide` class to all succeeding images after the first one.

```
<?php if( $element['#field_name'] == 'field_gallery') : ?>  
  <div class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes; ?>>
    <div <?php print $content_attributes; ?>>

      <?php $i = 0; foreach ($items as $delta => $item) : ?>

        <div class="field-item <?php if($i > 0) print 'hide '; print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>>
          <?php print render($item); $i++; ?>
        </div>

      <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to use a module like [Views Slideshow: Dynamic Display Block](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_ddblock) to produce what you're looking for ?

If not you should create a specific template for your field using a name like `field--field-name.tpl.php` ([Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656#field-suggestion)), put it in you theme folder and customize it.

You can use [theme_imagecache()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--imagecache--imagecache.module/function/theme_imagecache/6) if you're on Drupal 6 or [theme_image_style()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) on Drupal 7.

```
$img = theme('image_style', 
             array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 
                   'path' => $content['field_image'][0]['#item']['uri']
                  ));
```

Then you wrap your images in a using [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_attributes/7):

```
$attributes = Array('rel' => 'rel_text');

echo l('yourpath', $img, array('html' => TRUE, $attributes));
```

Comment: That code looks like it's what I've been waiting for (the second one with the l())! Sorry but in which template file do I type it in and where inside it? :-)

Comment: Have a look at templates name suggestion, also you can install [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to figure them out.